# How to use library in both testCompile and androidTestCompile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

Need power mock and mockito in both UI and UT test cases,

```
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9" // PowerMockito works on 2.8.9
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2"
```

This needed in UI test

```
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9" // PowerMockito works on 2.8.9
androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3"
androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0RC2"
```

Implementing both is producing unable to merge dex error

In build.gradle

//  multidex enabled true

//  included library   **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'**

How to solve this issue? And use libraries in both UI and UT?

Comment: Are you using `multidex` in your app?

Comment: Yeah I am using multidex in my app.